# webview inside listview on xamarin.forms

Tags: webview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I try to read an rss feed and display on the webview and listview. When I run my code into the Xamarin Android emulator, it is displaying as below. Display looks corrupted?

1. I dont know where are these triangles coming from on the right side?
2. [*Click here*][2]  for the rss feed url. I am reading the description element of each item and displaying them in the vebview. As you can see each description is pretty long but it is display only part of the description until the straight line for each. Why is it truncation?

   ListView.ItemTemplate>

   ```
        </StackLayout>               

     </ViewCell>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

and the convertor

```
 public class HtmlSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();

        if (value != null)
        {
            html.Html = value.ToString();
        }

        return html;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that your device doesn't burst into flames when you try that.  A WebView is not a lightweight control - trying to display multiple instances on the page at once is a horrible, terrible, not-good idea.  If you just want to display a small snippet of HTML there are much better ways to approach it.

Comment: Can you tell me please what is the better way!? I am new on xamarin.

Comment: I would just use a label and strip out any markup from the rss text

Comment: I have just thought to render html directly as there are image markups between the lines. it will be not easy to pickup them. Or do you think that maybe i can display 1 item at a time (1 page) rather then list and use kind of paging or pull to refresh logic to go to next item(page)? is something like that available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally just a bad idea to even try to nest a web view inside a list view. Even a nested scroll views can cause UX problems. I would recommend using a different kind of view for your cells.

**I think the good way to do it is to just try to grab the content and throw it in a label.**

I had seen a similar type of quest in Xamarin Forums : [***webview inside a listview***](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29909/webview-inside-a-listview)